# How to load a template-part based on a url wildcard?

Tags: php, theme-development, hooks

I'm trying to create a agenda in a custom Wordpress theme. On the agenda page there is a simple page-agenda.php template that will include some code that handles the index of the agenda. Quite simple.

But now I would like to 'listen' to the URL that contains a detail page of an agenda item. For example /agenda/1/event-name.

When I visit the above URL I get an page not found error. And when I try to load a template file based on the init hook of wordpress, no content seems to be added to the page and I keep getting the page-not-found page.

SO. How would I load a .php template file base on a URL wildcard like /agenda/1/event-name? So I can show the event data and not get a 404 message.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like instead of `page-agenda.php` and a Page, you may be better off with a Custom Post Type of "agenda". That way you'll have `archive-agenda.php` as the archive instead of a Page, and `single-agenda.php` to handle single agendas. I'm not sure where the "1" in your desired URL is coming from, but typically you would set up `/agenda/name-of-one-agenda/` style permalinks, and `/agenda/` as the archive.

Comment: A custom post type wouldn't be ideal in this case because the data comes from a external database. That would mean that there should be code written to sync the data with nodes in Wordpress. Might not be the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this solution in `functions.php`, thanks to the offical Wordpress documentation at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

First added a custom rewrite rule like so:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 
        '^agenda/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?page_id=10&agenda_id=$matches[1]&agenda_name=$matches[2]',
        'top' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0 );
```

Then this needed to be added:

```
function prefix_register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'agenda_id';
    $vars[] = 'agenda_name';

    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'prefix_register_query_var' );
```

Now URL's such as /agenda/1/event-title work like a charm! And passes the variables needed.

**PS: Remember to save the permalinks settings in the backend once again, or this code won't work!**